# Mule variable in MEL as String

Tags: mule, mel

i have an expression bellow to read a file from resources :

```
#[Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream('abc.txt')]
```

it worked fine, but i want to use a variable like this one:

```
#[Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(flowVars['fileName'])]
```

it does not work,

1. how can i make it work like the first one MEL ?
2. how can i read a file in absolute path "D://input/abc.txt" using MEL ?

Thanks for helps.

**resolved**

1. use `flowVars.filename` instead of `flowVars['fileName']` it worked, but i can't get it, i use logger with this MEL `#[flowVars['filename']]` and it work too but in the second MEL it failed.

Comment: seems correct to me, what error are you getting?

Comment: the second MEL return null payload, the first one return a file as stream

Comment: I tried reproducing this and both the first and second mel's return a java.io.BufferedInputStream, which is expected.

Comment: a second MEL worked with flowVars.filename, thanks. Can you take a look to 2nd question.

Comment: You are using a different case with the two different approaches. Variable names are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)  You are using a different case with the two different approaches. Variable names are case sensitive.

2)  Just use a FileInputStream:

```
 #[new FileInputStream("path")]
```

Or even better maybe to use the File transport/Mule Requester Module.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, Use variable name instead of using keyword "flowVars"

```
#[Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName)]
```